# Unity Script: How to gradually change a color of an object using color.lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a button that is suppose to change a colour of an object. Im using color.lerp but i need it to gradually change. like slowly. what i have now:

```
public Renderer engineBodyRenderer;
public float speed;
public Color startColor, endColor;
float startTime;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
    ChangeEngineColour();
}

public void ChangeEngineColour()
{
    float t = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    engineBodyRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t);
}
```

so the color of the object does change just not slowly. what am i missing?

Comment: You call `ChangeEngineColour();` only once in `Start` .. you could call it in `Update` as well to call it every frame.

Answer (score 3):

In your solution the method is only run ONCE, so only ONE color change can happen. Here's how I usually do it:

```
void Start() 
{
    // ... your other stuff 

    StartCoroutine(ChangeEngineColour());
}

private IEnumerator ChangeEngineColour()
{
    float tick = 0f;
    while (engineBodyRenderer.material.color != endColor)
    {
        tick += Time.deltaTime * speed;
        engineBodyRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, tick);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

By starting a Coroutine this code will run asyncronously beside the rest of the code and with `yield return null` it will loop in the same speed as your `Update()` functions, so essentially you've created an isolated Update() method, that run every frame and will gradually change the color every frame.

Comment: `asyncronously` is a bit missleading here ;)

Comment: How so? Coroutines do run asynchronously from a code perspective, you need to handle them conceptually like you would true asynchronous code.

Comment: Because they still run in the main thread. They are not really asynchronous in threading and CPU perspective. You have to tread real `async` and threaded executions very differently to Coroutines. I get what you ment and I agree with your answer. I'm just saying that calling it `asynchronous` is misleading as this usually referes to [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) or otherwise threaded code - which Coroutines clearly are not.

Comment: async or asynchrony in computing (and in this case) has nothing to do with which thread the code is running on. I believe the word you were looking for is concurrency. Also, awaiting an async function does not make it run on a new thread. Coroutines are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

And to change back and forth between colors gradually, replace this line from Fredrick:

```
engineBodyRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, tick);
```

to this:

```
engineBodyRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
```

So you will have:

[image]